# Is there anything we can do about delinquent questions?

Tags: discussion

The following question is old but popular and has a quality answer that the community agrees upon but the questioner is not bothered to mark it as answered.

[Set cellpadding and cellspacing in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css)

Similarly, following question is probably never going to be answered (since it is too specific and un-reproducible) nor closed (since it is relatively old and unpopular).

[Stupefyingly weird IE 9 Javascript bug: Altering doc title makes subsequent code execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491790/stupefyingly-weird-ie-9-javascript-bug-altering-doc-title-makes-subsequent-code)

Do we care that questions are left unresolved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no requirement that any answer ever be accepted to any particular question.

If you like an answer, vote it up. That makes the question formally 'answered'.

Comment: Reflecting upon your answer makes me remember all those times I told someone their accept rate was suboptimal. I felt a small pang of guilt. It's gone now.